# How to add append jquery function in magento

Tags: jquery

in my case I want to add the 'div1' class to the 'div2' class but I don't really know how to do it. I tested a code but after the else part, the code doesn't execute (just the append method not other function like alert()...), is there any syntax error for the Magento logic

this is error in console :

```
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function($){
    "use strict";
    return function myfunctionCheck()
    {
        //code
    }
     else {
        //code
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error seems unrelated with your custom jquery code

Comment: what happens if you remove your custom jquery code? will the error also gone?

Comment: all of them ? or juste the append line

Comment: yeah all the custom codes

Comment: the same error when i refresh the page

Comment: it means your jquery code is not the reason for error in the console. Try wrapping your `if` with `$(function(){

  // jQuery codes go here...

});`

Comment: i remove some code in requirejs-config.js file and error has gone thank you, but the append() method won't be executed; i can execute it and work fine but just in console debug not inside the phtml file

Comment: you can try my suggestion above, wrap your if statement with `$(function(){

  // your if statement code here ...

});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try this into your code part and you can increase and decrease time**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".div1").insertAfter($(".div2"));
}, 3000);
```